# How to create a progress bar inside a sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is about increase the width of a div inside a li.

Basically, when a user scrolls, the sidebar (Right Hand Side) li increase the **span** (*red background color*) from 0 to 100. In other words, if the first corresponding div is in view, then the corresponding li elements' **span** will increase/decrease from **0 to 100%** as a user scrolls down or up. This will indicate how much of the div the user has scrolled.

I have a sample code pen that shows what I am trying to do 
https://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/xdVJQp

My CSS looks like

```
.sidebar {
position: fixed;
max-width: 300px;
&__list {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 2px solid #f3f2f0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
// The primary red bar at the bottom that increases in width with scroll
span {
    background-color: red;
    height: 5px;
}
```

}

The problem is in the js
In the JS, I guess
1. Need to calculate height of the corresponding div
2. Increase the span by the certain percentage depending on the height calculated on 1.

I can not seem to figure out the code at all. Can anyone help?

```
// Checks whether an elem gets into view of the window
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    'use strict';
    if (elem.length > 0) {
        var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();
        var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
        return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }
}

var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    // Increase & Decrease width of the span of li as you scroll

        var height = $('section-just-in').height();
        var incrementBy = 300 / height;


        $('.sidebar__list span').animate({
            // increase width from 0 till 100%
            width : width + incrementBy
        });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### something like this:

#### https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/ZKOaBY

### or jsfiddle here:

#### https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/Lw72csjd/

1st get height for each section

2nd on scroll, check the progress for each section

last apply the progress bar to each button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var theone = $('#section-just-in');
  var thetwo = $('#videos');
  var thethree = $('#aboutteam');
  var theone_h, thetwo_h, thethree_h;

  theone_h = theone.innerHeight();
  thetwo_h = thetwo.innerHeight();
    // remove the window height cus
    // we are not able to full scroll down when we hit the bottom of the page
  thethree_h = thethree.innerHeight() - $(window).height();

  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var page_height = $("body").scrollTop();

    var pos_2 = page_height > theone_h ? page_height - theone_h : 0;
    var pos_3 = page_height > (thetwo_h+theone_h) ? (page_height - (+thetwo_h + +theone_h)) : 0;
    var progress_1 = (page_height / theone_h) >= 1 ? 100 : (page_height / theone_h) * 100;
    var progress_2 = (pos_2 / thetwo_h) >= 1 ? 100 : (pos_2 / thetwo_h) * 100;
    var progress_3 = ((pos_3) / thethree_h) >= 1 ? 100 : ((pos_3) / thethree_h) * 100;

    $("ul li:nth-child(1) span").stop().animate({
      "width": progress_1 + '%'
    }, 0);
    $("ul li:nth-child(2) span").stop().animate({
      "width": progress_2 + '%'
    }, 0);
    $("ul li:nth-child(3) span").stop().animate({
      "width": progress_3 + '%'
    }, 0);
  });




  // Checks whether an elem gets into view of the window
  function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    'use strict';
    if (elem.length > 0) {
      var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
      var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();
      var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
      return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect . Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @Daniel H, Looks perfect. Just a small issue. If there are lot of elements before the start of the first one (i.e $('#section-just-in') ) , the progress bar starts too soon. Can it be started when the section just-in is in view?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var height,
    incrementBy,
    visible_height;

$(document).ready(function(){
    visible_height = $('.section-just-in').innerHeight(); 
});

$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_top = Math.max( $("html").scrollTop(), $("body").scrollTop());

    incrementBy = (100 * scroll_top) / visible_height / 1.4;

    $('.sidebar__list span').stop().animate({
        "width" : incrementBy
    });
});
```

Just replace everything after `isScrolledIntoView` function and it should work.

Comment: Looks close. I think OP wanted the spans to increase one after the other, with the corresponding section.

Comment: Thanks @Aca85. However, what I am really looking is to increase the width of each, i.e increase one after another with the corresponding section.